# как отключить очередь из Toast.makeText - java

Tags: java

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в которой код.

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Не создавалась очередь из нажатий а просто выводилось один раз ?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно чтобы тост был показан только один раз:

```
private boolean alreadyShown = false;
public void onClick (View v) {
    if (!alreadyShown) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        alreadyShown = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно чтобы новый тост не создавался, пока виден предыдущий:

```
private boolean alreadyShown = false;
public void onClick (View v) {
    if (!alreadyShown) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                alreadyShown = false;
            }
        }, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        alreadyShown = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно дополнить ответ, нажав на кнопку "править" под ним, а не создавать дополнительный. PS. ``shown``, а не ``showed``.

Comment: @Эникейщик не уверен, но думаю, так всё же логичнее. Ответы-то по сути разные. Иначе зачем на сайте дана такая возможность?

Comment: Такая возможность не "дана", а "не отнята". Разные ответы "по сути" или не разные - не имеет значения.

Comment: @Эникейщик, а какие-то доводы в пользу именно объединения ответов в один есть? или лично вам просто так больше понравилось бы?

Answer (score 0):

Создавать объект тоста только один раз:

```
private Toast mMyToast; //

...

    if (mMyToast == null) {
        mMyToast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    mMyToast.setText("Text"); // Обновляем текст тоста
    mMyToast.show(); // Показываем тост, а если он показывается то просто продлевается время показа
```